# How to list files in HDD which shows read only

Tags: command-line, hard-drive

I'm trying to list all files and folder in my external HDD, connected to laptop by using command `ls -R > abc.txt`  and I get a message as `bash: abc.txt: Read-only file system . kindly help.

Comment: If your file-system has *flipped* to RO (ie. changed from RW ot RO) then a serious error has been detected, and that is a safety measure to avoid data corruption. You should look for the cause & correct it (it's usually fixed by a `fsck` or *file system check*).  If it was mounted RO, you need to `umount` (unmount) then `mount` (re-mount) it RW (read-write), but a RO *file-system* is a serious warning sign of problems (unless you mounted it RO).   You can't save data to a RO file-system (what the READ ONLY means). You can only save data to a file-system mounted as RW or READ WRITE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute `ls -R` on a readonly filesystem, however the file that you are redirecting the output of the command to must be on a writeable filesystem. So in general

```
ls -R > path/to/writeable/dir/abc.txt
```

The simplest option is to write to a file in your home directory

```
ls -R > ~/abc.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance.